# Push vector into `MultiArray`-Message and publish it

Tags: ros, std-msgs, multiarray, publisher, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I simply try to push multiple `vector<double>` into the message format, but can not figure it out also I looked at [this](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayLayout.html) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/37185/how-to-initialize-a-uint8multiarray-message/).

```
     std_msgs::Float64MultiArray msg;
    vector<double> vec1 = { 1.1, 2., 3.1};
    vector<double> vec2 = { 3., 4.1, 2., 3.1};

     vector<double>::const_iterator itr, end(vec.end());
    for(itr = vec.begin(); itr!= end; ++itr) {
            // how to use the pointer  *itr here? to push vec1 and vec2 into msg ?
    }
```

//I also want to specify the layout and tried to use some of these lines:

```
    msg.data.clear();
    msg.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());
    msg.layout.dim[0].size = *da;
    msg.layout.dim[0].stride = 1;
    msg.layout.dim[0].label = "typ i";
```

**Edit: Solution**
So as said below one cannot push **multiple** arrays(vector is basically 1D-array)  into **one** message as originally thought. So it does not behave like a container object for multiple variables but only holds one *i-D array.* 
To fix this I could sum up all vectors into **one** *2-D array* and push it into the `msg`:
The title `MultiArray` is quite misleading then, but once known its ok.
 (I could not get to work with `data.extend(..)`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226726/push-vector-into--%60multiarray%60-message-and-publish-it/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-16**:
sorry for the typo. updated my answer with the correct field name.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-17**:
I confused the python `extend()` with the C++ vector's `insert()`. Answer updated and should work now. Note that insert() is faster than an element-by-element push, because it only expands the size of the vector once.

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-18**:
Explanations on `insert()` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/c-appending-a-vector-to-a-vector), furthermore this leads back to pushing multiple vectors inside the array: make all have same `vec.size()` and specify it in the `.stride`. So each row represents one vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MultiArray messages are for publishing multi-dimensional arrays; not for publishing multiple arrays within the same message.

For example, a vector or list is a one-dimensional array, and a matrix would be a two-dimensional array.

You need to set up the `dim` array with the dimensions of your array. For a 1-d array, one element with the length. For a 2-d array or matrix, your `dim` array would have two elements; one for the height of the matrix, and a second for the width of the matrix.

Once you have `dim` set up, you store your data in the `data` field in row-major order.

As an example, if you wanted to put your `vec1` in a MultiArray, you would do:

```
vector<double> vec1 = { 1.1, 2., 3.1};
std_msgs::Float64MultiArray msg;

// set up dimensions
msg.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());
msg.layout.dim[0].size = vec1.size();
msg.layout.dim[0].stride = 1;
msg.layout.dim[0].label = "x"; // or whatever name you typically use to index vec1

// copy in the data
msg.data.clear();
msg.data.insert(msg.data.end(), vec1.begin(), vec1.end());
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-03-28**:
Why do you need the `clear()` call on `msg.data`?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-28**:
It's not necessary in this example, but it's nice to clear the array if you're re-using the same message object.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a complete example (please edit if any mistakes found)

```
vector<double> vec;
while (ros::ok()){
    int i = 0;
    std_msgs::Float64MultiArray msg;
    vec = c.getvec(typ); //function which initializes the vector
    
    msg.layout.dim.push_back(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension());  
    msg.layout.dim[0].size = vec.size();
    msg.layout.dim[0].stride = 1;
    msg.layout.dim[0].label = strings[typ+4];
    
    
    //push data into data blob
    vector<double>::const_iterator itr, end(vec.end());
    for(itr = vec.begin(); itr!= end; ++itr) {
        //cout<<*itr<<endl;
        msg.data.push_back(*itr); 
    }/**/
    
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spinOnce();

    //clear stuff and sleep
    vec.clear();
    loop_rate.sleep();
}
```

The result on `rostopic echo` looks like:

```
layout: 
  dim: 
    - 
      label: /listener_socket/orient
      size: 6
      stride: 1
  data_offset: 0
data: [35589264796691.0, 3.0, 3.0, 167.94601, 1.6419868, 0.15967418]
---
```

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [james P M](https://answers.ros.org/users/56428/james-p-m/) on 2021-11-21**:
how to assign data into defined indices for example a[2] = 12.